# Prove that $(L[a,b], ||\cdot ||)$ is a normed linear space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

I want to prove that $(L[a,b], ||\cdot ||)$ is a normed linear space with norm
$$||f(x)|| = \int_a^bx^2|f(x)|dx.$$
First, let $\lambda \in \mathbb{R},$ then it is clear that by properties of integration that 
$$||\lambda f(x)|| = \int_a^bx^2|\lambda f(x)|dx= |\lambda |\int_a^bx^2|f(x)|dx = |\lambda | ||f(x)||.$$
Now, we recall that functions in $L[a,b]$ has domain in $\mathbb{R}$, that is, we consider functions $\varphi: L[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$. Thus, for $f,g \in L[a,b]$ and the triangle inequality for real numbers, it follows that 
$$|f(x) + g(x)| \leq |f(x)| + |g(x)|,$$
but for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we have that $x^2 > 0$, thus
$$x^2|f(x) + g(x)| \leq x^2(|f(x)| + |g(x)|),$$
and by the properties of integration, we have 
$$\int_a^bx^2|f(x) + g(x)|dx \leq \int_a^bx^2(|f(x)| + |g(x)|)dx,$$
and therefore
$$||f(x)+ g(x)|| \leq ||f(x)|| + ||g(x)||$$
as required. Now, I want to prove that $$||f(x)|| = 0 \Leftrightarrow f(x) = 0.$$ 
Suppose first that $f(x) = 0$, then 
$$\int_a^bx^2f(x) = 0,$$
and therefore $||f(x)|| = 0$ as required. Now, under the assumption that $||f(x)|| = 0$, we have
$$\int_a^bx^2|f(x)|dx = 0.$$
If $f(x) = 0$, then we are done. Let's suppose that $f(x) \neq 0$. In particular, we have that $|f(x)| > 0$ and thus $x^2|f(x)| > 0$. The integral gives
$$\int_a^b x^2|f(x)| dx > 0,$$
which gives a contradiction because we are assuming that $||f||= 0$. Therefore $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: first assume $f$ is piecewise continuous. then show that the closure (for your norm) of the set of (piecewise) continuous functions on $[a,b]$ spans the whole Banach space

Comment: (and you are considering equivalence  classes of functions : $f \equiv g$ whenever $\|f-g\| = 0$)

Comment: Yes I am considering classes of equivalence functions. I am not understanding why we need the assumptions of piecewise continuous.

Comment: you can consider what you want, polynomials, trigonometric polynomials, continuous functions, anything for which $\|f\| = 0 \implies f(x)  =0$ for every $x \in [a,b]$, then you only have to prove that every $f$ of your Banach space (of equivalence classes of functions) is the limit of a Cauchy sequence of such (continuous) functions

Comment: Use the fact that $-|f| \le f \le |f|$

Comment: @mwomath I modify my approach using your hint. Is this the correct reasoning?

Comment: The last two statements are surly wrong. The counter example is take $f(x)=(x-\frac{1}{2})$ clearly $f \ne 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]\backslash \left\{ {{\textstyle{{1} \over 2}}} \right\}$, and $\int_0^1{f(x)dx}=0$. Accordingly the statement after that is not true.

Comment: Fact: If $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and $\int_0^1{x^nf(x)dx}=0$, $n=0,1,2,\cdots$. Then  $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. But as you have written no, $f$ is not continuous (only belongs to L[a,b]) so not linear space. So the continuity assumption on $f$ is required.

Comment: One brute force approach, though it won't work in some very similar problems, is to note that your norm, which I'll denote by $\| f(x) \|_{L^1(x^2 dx,[a,b])}$, is the same as $\frac{1}{3} \| f(x^{1/3}) \|_{L^1(dx,[a^3,b^3])}$. So the problem reduces to showing that $f(x^{1/3})$ is Lebesgue integrable, which is not difficult.

Comment: @Ian I do not understand your approach either. I can't see why it works out.

Comment: My trick is just to change variables to $u=x^3$, so that $du=3x^2dx$. Then again, it may not be clear that one can change variables to you at this point...

Comment: I know that $f$ is Lebesgue integral, that is, $$\int_a^b |f(x)| dx < \infty.$$ It doesn't follow directly that in particular $\int_a^b |f(x^{1/3})| dx < \infty$?

Comment: Well, one way is to *change back* to the original problem and then use the fact that $x^2 \leq \max \{ a^2,b^2 \}$ to bound the integral. Then deduce the triangle inequality after you have changed variables (to avoid having to prove it directly).